# JavaScript inside Angular's (1.4.7) ng-view doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a partial page that goes inside the ng-view and I have JS code related to nothing other than that page and so I'd like for it to be included in that page only since I only need it there and to avoid overhead in my index.html, I tried injection like using `ng-bind-html` that didn't work.

Here's some code to help understand what's going on.

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">

    <title>Node and Angular App</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="libs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- JS -->
    <script src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ANGULAR CUSTOM -->
    <script src="js/controllers/TestCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="js/appRoutes.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-app="sampleApp">
    <div class="container">
        <nav>
            <a href="/test">Test</a>
       </nav>

        <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
       <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**TestCtrl.js**

```
angular.module('TestCtrl', ['ngSanitize']).controller('TestController', function($scope) {

  var str = '<h1>this shows</h1><script>alert("hello")</script><h1>this doesn\'t show</h1>';

  $scope.content = function() { return str; }
});
```

**test.html**

`<div class="jumbotron" ng-bind-html="content()"></div>`

**appRoutes.js**

```
angular.module('appRoutes', []).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider

  .when('/test', {
    templateUrl: 'views/test.html',
    controller: 'TestController'
  })

 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);
```

**app.js**

`var app = angular.module('sampleApp', ['ngRoute', 'appRoutes', 'TestCtrl']);`

Comment: Sentence too long to think about.

Comment: `ng-bind-html` will not compile that scope..Simply binding will not work when you reder html using `ng-bind-html`

Comment: @PankajParkar are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question but if you want to inject html into your view, try adding ngSanitize to the list of dependencies in your module, them you can have:

```
controller("mainCtrl", ['$sce', function($sce){
    //function that returns trusted html
    this.htmlStuff = function(){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml("<p>Html String</p>");
    }
}]);
```

then in your view, you can have

```
<div ng-controller='mainCtrl as main'>
    <div ng-bind-html="main.htmlStuff()"></div>
</div>
```

if this isn't what you meant, then you have to rephrase the question

Comment: @RichardHall you need to `ngSanitize` module in your app, also need to include `angular-sanitize.js`

Comment: @RichardHall Try changing this line in you code:  `$scope.content = function() { return str; }` to `$scope.content = function() { return $sce.trustAsHtml(str); }`. if that doesn't work, you might have to split the string into HTML and JS parts and use $sce.trustAsHtml() and $sce.trustAsJs() on the appropriate parts.

Comment: @user2994666 Nope, only the HTML parts worked and they show, as for the JS parts, they don't render (I've looked at the browser's inspector and the DIV i put it in is empty)

Comment: @RichardHall there are separate functions for returning javascript and html trustAsJs() and trustAsHtml() you'll have to split them up. [Check out the $sce docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce) . Is it really worth the stress though?